# 'For' loop for reading multiple csv files from a google storage bucket into 1 Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-storage, dask

I currently have 31 .csv files (all with the same identical structure - 60 cols wide and about 5000 rows deep) that I'm trying to read in from a google storage bucket into 1 pandas dataframe using a 'FOR' loop and I keep getting a 'timeout' error after 6 mins.

Upon doing some testing, I have noticed that I'm able to read one .csv file a time through it, but once I introduce 2 or more, I get the timeout error.  This makes me think that my code is the problem rather than the size of the data.

Code is below  (Should I be using pd.concat at any stage in the for loop?) help would be appreciated

```
def stage1eposdata(data, context):  

    from google.cloud import storage
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import pandas as pd
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    import io
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    from googleapiclient import discovery
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    import google.auth
    import math

    destination_path1 = 'gs://staged_data/ddf-*_stet.csv'  

## Source Buckets #
    raw_epos_bucket = 'raw_data'
    cleaned_epos_bucket = 'staged_data'

    # Confirming Oauth #
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

    # Confirming Connection #
    raw_epos_data = storage_client.bucket(raw_epos_bucket)
    cleaned_epos_data = storage_client.bucket(cleaned_epos_bucket)

    df  = pd.DataFrame()

    for file in list(raw_epos_data.list_blobs(prefix='2019/')):
        file_path="gs://{}/{}".format(file.bucket.name, file.name)
        df = df.append(pd.read_csv(file_path),sort =False)

    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1, sort=True)
    ddf.to_csv(destination_path1, index=True, sep=',')
```

Comment: try save in a list  and out of the loop use `pd.concat` to join them all.
in each iteration loop you store a dataframe in a position in the list, for example call it `my_dataframe_list`. out of loop: `pd.concat(my_dataframe_list)`. Tell me if it works.
Note that in this way you do not use the append method in each iteration of the loop

Comment: So what would the `my_dataframe_list` line of code look like in the for loop? I'm intrigued as to how you can avoid using the `append` method in this step

Comment: I added an answer, if it doesn't work I try edit it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
## Source Buckets #
    raw_epos_bucket = 'raw_data'
    cleaned_epos_bucket = 'staged_data'

    # Confirming Oauth #
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

    # Confirming Connection #
    raw_epos_data = storage_client.bucket(raw_epos_bucket)
    cleaned_epos_data = storage_client.bucket(cleaned_epos_bucket)


    my_dataframe_list=[]

    for file in list(raw_epos_data.list_blobs(prefix='2019/')):
        file_path="gs://{}/{}".format(file.bucket.name, file.name)
        my_dataframe_list.append(pd.read_csv(file_path))

    df=pd.concat(my_dataframe_list)
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1, sort=True)
    ddf.to_csv(destination_path1, index=True, sep=',')
```

`pd.concat` joins a list of DataFrame. So in each iteration of the loop you keep the dataframe in the list `my_dataframe_list` and out of the loop concatenate the list. 
if the columns match it should work.

Comment: it works when I run this on my local machine but when I refactor it into a google cloud function it only works for about half the .csv files before it times out again.  I will have to revisit to google cloud docs to see what could be driving it

Comment: You might have already done this, but JIC: you definitely want to increase the default timeout in this case. It's 1 minute by default but you can go up to 9 minutes. The docs mention how to do it with CLI and GUI here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that dask can do this type of thing very well due to its 'lazy' computation feature.  My solution is below

```
## Source Buckets #
raw_epos_bucket = 'raw_data'
cleaned_epos_bucket = 'staged_data'

# Confirming Oauth #
storage_client = storage.Client()
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

# Confirming Connection #
raw_epos_data = storage_client.bucket(raw_epos_bucket)
cleaned_epos_data = storage_client.bucket(cleaned_epos_bucket)

my_dataframe_list = []
my_dataframe_list = dd.read_csv('gs://raw_data/*.csv')# '*' is wild card no need to do any more 'For' Loops!

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1, sort=True)
ddf.to_csv(destination_path1, index=True, sep=',')
```